How to set camera/video to 220 fps?
In Xcode, with Swift, can FPS for VisionKit or AVFoundation be set programmatically to watch/record at the 220 fps setting?

You can use AVFoundation's AVCaptureSession and set the AVCaptureDevice's activeFormat to an appropriate format and the frame durations to 1.0/220 as shown here.
From what I've seen of VisionKit you can supply it with CMSampleBuffers from your AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, so that's one way to process frames at 220 fps in VisionKit.
